# Python code output isn't displaying properly

Tags: python, output, modular

My code seems fine but when i run it and input the sales it wont show the commission.

[image: picture]

this is python btw.

```html
keep_going = "y"

while keep_going == "y":
    sales = float(input("Enter the amount of sales: "))
    comm_rate = 10

    commission = sales * comm_rate

    print ("The commission is: "),commission
    
    keep_going = input("Do you want to calculate another commission? (Enter y for yes): ")

main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
print ("The commission is: "),commission
```

To:

```
print ("The commission is: ", commission)
```

Comment: @polskiebmw: On this site, show your appreciation by upvoting all the useful answers. You do that by clicking the up-arrow at the top-left of the answer. In addition accept the best answer by clicking the checkmark near the top-left of the answer. That is better than saying thanks in a comment. It also helps others to see your question was answered.